# How to run C# code on Linux server easily?

Tags: c#, linux

I have a PHP website which I am learning PHP on, which is on Linux server. How can I run this C# code without conflicting with current PHP code? When I open URL like `site.com/hello.cs`, it just shows the whole thing as text? What do I need to run this code on server?

```
public class Hello1
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at mono. I have no idea about how to actually make it work but its supposed to be relatively stable.

Comment: You want to run C# code on the server, or just display the contents of the file?  The question seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: yeah - look at http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# files (.cs) need to be compiled before they run. Check out the [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)....

Here's the basic outline of what you need to do to get a web site running:

1. Download MonoDevelop (the Mono analogue to MS Visual Studio) from the link above.
2. Go to File > New > Solution
3. Create an ASP.NET or MVC project from under C# at the left.
4. Design your web site and deploy to your web server. (I realize this glosses over a lot, but post another question here when you hit a snag.)

Also, just so you know, your code example above won't render as a web page as is. That's code for a command-line-based application. MonoDevelop comes out of the box with decent templates for web sites though.

Comment: i know it is stupid question. but there is no easier way to do this? or if i write code in visual studio can i deploy that somehow to the website?

Comment: C# isn't a scripting language like PHP is. It can't be run directly from the web server from source, so unless there's some trick that I haven't heard of, you'll need to do this.

Comment: Actually you don't have to compile - Aspx + CS pages can be compiled on demand if server is correctly configured. No personal expirience, but following link looks like a reasonable walk through for configuring ASP.Net on Linux box - http://www.ivankristianto.com/software-development/mono/howto-run-asp-net-on-linux-with-apache-web-server-mono-mod_mono/760/

Comment: @Gurnor: >> "but there is no easier way to do this?" - Sure, you can actually compile simple C# programs from the command line, similar to a single PHP script. You use csc compiler on Windows and mcs on Linux/Mono. But a Visual Studio project is actually easier in the long run.